# Postfix sender_dependent_relayhost_maps: do not relay a specific address

Tags: postfix

Let's say I don't set up `relayhost` because I want by default to send all the emails by the server itself.

Then for some domains in the "FROM", I want to relay to a specific relay. For that I would use a `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender` and inside it, I would put something like:

```
@mydomain.com         ses.amazon.com
```

That is all very straight forward.

---

Now, what do I put in "relay_by_sender" file to say that I want all my emails relayed for my domain, but one in particular. How would I do that? E.g

```
@mydomain.com           ses.amazon.com
no-relay@mydomain.com   null?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Postfix 2.6 or later, I guess you can return the keyword `DUNNO`, which is documented in [sender_dependent_relayhost_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps) topic.

```
no-relay@mydomain.com   DUNNO
@mydomain.com           ses.amazon.com
```

If it doesn't work and you use Postfix 2.7 or newer, I suggest you to replace `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` with [sender_dependent_default_transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps). The latter provides more flexibility:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender

# /etc/postfix/relay_by_sender
no-relay@mydomain.com   smtp
@mydomain.com           smtp:[ses.amazon.com]
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed the big DUNNO in the doc after that many readings... I need a break I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not  sure to understand if you want to use the default transport (send by the server itself) for a specific mail address, or completely deny relaying for this particular sender address.

If you want to use the default transport, @anderson-medeiros-gomes's  solution seems appropriate.

If you want to deny relaying for this mail, you may also use the special `error:` mailer documented in the [manpage of transport](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html):

```
       The error mailer can be used to bounce mail:

            .example.com     error:mail for *.example.com is not deliverable
```

In your case would give for `/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender`:

```
no-relay@mydomain.com   error:Relaying not allowed for no-relay address
@mydomain.com           ses.amazon.com
```