# Don't use relayhost for a single domain (sender/from)

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to send one domain based on the sender (from) out directly to the mx of the recipient. However the following doesn't work:

## main.cf

```
relayhost = ses.amazon.com
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay
```

## sender_relay

```
@domain.com   DUNNO
```

I've also tried doing it the transport_maps way and still no joy. How do I tell postfix to send any email coming from @domain.com out normally without a relay? Seems like a simple problem but I am stumped.

Comment: May be this helps? https://serverfault.com/questions/770002/postfix-sender-dependent-relayhost-maps-do-not-relay-a-specific-address

Comment: Sadly, no, that didn't work. Turns out I needed to use `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` with `default_transport` set. Likely because that answer isn't working from a "catchall" mentality, only from a single domain perspective. My solution has hundreds of domains being relayed with only one needing to be sent out directly.

Answer (score 2):

## The Fix

Turns out I needed this in main.cf:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
default_transport = relay:ses.amazon.com
```

Without the following directives:

`relayhost`, `transport_maps`

## sender_transport

```
@domainone.com smtp:
@domaintwo.com.au smtp:
```

Having a catchall in `sender_transport` did not work.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as the accepted solution please?